# Как сделать вложенный blueprint с параметрами? (flask)

Tags: python, flask

Имеется код

```
bp1 = Blueprint('schools', __name__)
bp2 = Blueprint('class', __name__)


@bp1.route('/<school_id>')
def school(school_id):
    ...


@bp2.route('/<class_id>')
def class_view(school_id, class_id):
    ...


bp1.register_blueprint(bp2, url_prefix='/class')
app.register_blueprint(bp1, url_prefix='/school')
```

Как сделать так, чтобы url функции class_view был /school/<school_id>/class/<class_id>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bp1 = Blueprint('schools', __name__, url_prefix='/schools/<int:school_id>')
bp2 = Blueprint('class', __name__, url_prefix='/class/<int:class_id>')

@bp1.route('/')
def school(school_id):
    return f'{school_id=}'

@bp2.route('/')
def class_view(school_id, class_id):
    return f'{school_id=}{class_id=}'

bp1.register_blueprint(bp2)
app.register_blueprint(bp1)
```

Вывод url_map

```
'/schools/<school_id>/'
'/schools/<school_id>/class/<class_id>/'
```